# VueJS google maps api not rendering custom markers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue2-google-maps to render a map and mark locations on the map. Below are the map components and the props passed to it.

```
<gmap-map id="map" :center="center" :zoom="5" map-type-id="terrain">
    <gmap-marker
      v-for="(marker, index) in markers"
      :key="index"
      :position="getPosition(marker.coords)"
      :animation="2"
      :icon="getMarkerIcon(marker.type)">
    </gmap-marker>
</gmap-map>
```

The getMarkerIcon method returns the options for an SVG icon to be rendered like so.

```
getMarkerIcon(type) {
  const labels = {
    paid: "client/public/img/icons/Paid.svg",
    errorPaid: "client/public/img/icons/PaidError.svg",
    label: "client/public/img/icons/Label.svg",
    errorLabel: "client/public/img/icons/LabelError.svg",
  };

  const options = {
    url: labels[type],
    size: { width: 60, height: 90, f: "px", b: "px" },
    scaledSize: { width: 30, height: 45, f: "px", b: "px" },
  };

  return options;
},
```

If I don't pass the icon prop, markers get rendered with the standard marker from the API. If I pass the icon prop with the method, they do not render, no error shows up in the console. I tried to just pass the icon URL without any size, but still, it doesn't show up. To mention there are only 4 types of markers as per the label object in the method.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to use `require(<path-to-icon>)` in order to render it, this is nowhere mentioned in the official documentation.